# State Setter not setting complete state next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I do not know if this is a problem with the state setting, or if it is a problem with my map rendering, however, when I am trying to set the state of an array variable, I only get one of the elements to show. When I print out the elements inside the array it shows everything, but when I set the state it doesn't work. I think it may be due to it being an async function, as that is the only thing separating this and a similar function in the code. I have all of the state settings and fetching done inside the use effect, but even then I can only get one element to map.

```
const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);
    const [listDocuments, setListDocuments] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    
    const dataFetchedRef = useRef(false);
    const {currentUser} = UseAuth();
    
    const router = useRouter()


    const [averagePrice, setAveragePrice] = useState({})

    function getLoc() {
        if (currentUser) {
            return 'users/' + currentUser.uid + '/userInvestments'
        } else {
            return 'users/TestDocumentForDatabase/userInvestments'
        };
    }

    
useEffect(() => {
        if (!currentUser) {
            router.push('/login');
        } else {
            if(dataFetchedRef.current) return;
            dataFetchedRef.current = true;
            

            const setData = async() => {
                let data = []
                let avgMap = new Map()

                const loc = getLoc();
                const q = query(collection(db, loc));
                const snapshot = await getDocs(q)

                snapshot.forEach(async doc => {       
                    const obj = doc.data()
                    data.push(obj)
                    let tic = doc.data().stockTicker;
                    
                    if (avgMap.has(tic)) {
                        console.log("Has")
                        let data = avgMap.get(tic)
                        const type = doc.data().type;
                        let newShares = parseFloat(data.shares);
                        let newPrice = parseFloat(data.price);
                        const oldAmount = newShares * newPrice
                        if (type === "buy") {
                            newShares = newShares + parseFloat(doc.data().shares);
                            newPrice = (oldAmount + parseFloat(doc.data().price))/newShares;
                        } else {
                            newShares = newShares - parseFloat(doc.data().shares);
                            newPrice = (oldAmount - parseFloat(doc.data().price))/newShares;
                        }

                        const newData = {
                            price: newPrice,
                            shares: newShares,
                            stockTicker: tic,
                        }
                        avgMap.set(tic, newData)
                    } else {
                        console.log("Doesnt Have")
                        avgMap.set(tic, doc.data())
                    }
                })


                let retList = []
                avgMap.forEach(async (value, key) => {
                    const newPrice = await getStockPrice(key)
                    const currentPrice = parseFloat(newPrice.toFixed(2))
                    const pl = (parseFloat(value.shares)*(currentPrice - parseFloat(value.price))).toFixed(2)
                    const fixedPrice = (value.price).toFixed(2)
                    let insertAvg = {
                        ticker: key,
                        shares: value.shares,
                        averagePrice: fixedPrice,
                        currentPrice,
                        profitLoss: pl,
                        dividendYield: "Coming Soon"
                    }
                    retList.push(insertAvg)
                    setListDocuments([...listDocuments, insertAvg])
                    console.log(retList)

                    console.log(listDocuments)
                }) 
                
                console.log(retList)
                // setListDocuments(retList)
                console.log(listDocuments)
                setDocuments(data)
                console.log(documents)

                // data.forEach(doc => {
                    
                // })
                // (Object.keys(averageData).map(tic => {
                //     console.log("Tic" + tic)
                // }))

                setLoading(false)
            }
            setData()
            console.log(documents)
        }
    }, [listDocuments, documents])
    return (
        <div className='flex justify-center items-center flex-col gap-5'> 
             {!loading && 
                
                    <div className="container bg-white rounded px-20">
                        <div>
                        <table className="w-full flex flex-row flex-no-wrap sm:bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden sm:shadow-lg my-5">
                            <thead className="text-white">
                                {listDocuments?.map(doc => {
                                    return (<tr className="bg-gray-600 flex flex-col flex-nowrap sm:table-row rounded-lg sm:rounded-none mb-2 sm:mb-0">
                                        <th className="p-3 text-left">Type</th>
                                        <th className="p-3 text-left">Shares</th>
                                        <th className="p-3 text-left">Price</th>
                                        <th className="p-3 text-left">Return</th>
                                        <th className="p-3 text-left" width="110px">Actions</th>
                                    </tr>)
                                })}
                            
                            </thead>
                            <tbody className="flex-1 sm:flex-none text-black">
                                {listDocuments?.map(doc => {
                                    return (
                                        <tr className="flex flex-col flex-nowrap sm:table-row mb-2 sm:mb-0">
                                            <td className="border-grey-light border hover:bg-gray-100 p-3">John Covv</td>
                                            <td className="border-grey-light border hover:bg-gray-100 p-3 truncate">contato@johncovv.com</td>
                                            <td className="border-grey-light border hover:bg-gray-100 p-3 truncate">contato@johncovv.com</td>
                                            <td className="border-grey-light border hover:bg-gray-100 p-3 text-red-400 hover:text-red-600 hover:font-medium cursor-pointer">Delete</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        {tableizeData()}
                    </div>




                
            }
           ..... more variations of table designs
```

This is the rendering aspect of the functional component.

```
{
 listDocuments?.map(doc => {
       return (<tr className="bg-gray-600 flex flex-col flex-nowrap 
       sm:table-row rounded-lg sm:rounded-none mb-2 sm:mb-0">
               ... more code to show data
```

I have the same code but instead, it is

```
{
 documents?.map((doc) => {
     return (
          <tr key={doc.ticker}>
               <td className="px-6 py-2 text-center">
               ... more code to show data
```

and it works fine. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
let retList = []
avgMap.forEach(async(value, key) => {
  const newPrice = await getStockPrice(key)
  const currentPrice = parseFloat(newPrice.toFixed(2))
  const pl = (parseFloat(value.shares) * (currentPrice - parseFloat(value.price))).toFixed(2)
  const fixedPrice = (value.price).toFixed(2)
  let insertAvg = {
    ticker: key,
    shares: value.shares,
    averagePrice: fixedPrice,
    currentPrice,
    profitLoss: pl,
    dividendYield: "Coming Soon"
  }
  retList.push(insertAvg)
  // Don't setter in for-loop
  // setListDocuments([...listDocuments, insertAvg])
  console.log(retList)

  console.log(listDocuments)
});
// You should set state once after for-loop
setListDocuments((prev)=> [...prev, ...retList]);
```

Comment: I am running rext js 12. I do not know if that makes a difference, but your version of the code does not provide elements to screen either.

Comment: @Dotman my answer is not whole code. It is just a part of your code.

Comment: As you can see, I set the state of documents normally, as an array. This does not work however for the other array

Comment: i have modified the code and it works, but it does not map now.

Comment: @Dotman could you show me whole code?

Comment: I edited the post to contain more code.